# How can you filter search by matching String to a field in Algolia?

Tags: filtering, algolia

I'm trying to create filters for a search on an Android app where a specific field in Algolia must exactly match the given String in order to come up as a hit. For example if Algolia has a field like "foo" and I only want to return hits where "foo" is equal to "bar", then I would expect that I would have to use a line of code like this:

```
query.setFilters("foo: \"bar\"");
```

Any guesses as to why this isn't working like I see in the examples or how to do so?

Comment: `query.setFilters("foo:bar")` should work. Did you add `foo` to `attributesForFacetting` in your settings? It's needed for this kind of filtering to work. https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/android/parameters/attributesForFaceting/#attributesforfaceting

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I thought that [`attributesForFaceting`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/android/parameters/attributesForFaceting/#attributesforfaceting) was done by setting what was searchable or not. It was on a different page within the dashboard than I was previously using. Thanks @pixelastic.